# problem with data output from the database node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

this code renders the page and prints the text to the console, but does not increase the value in the database

````
 result.findOneAndUpdate({name:'score7'} ,{$inc:{text2:"11"}});
console.log('123');
next();
}, function (req, res) {
result.find({$or:  [{name:'police'} ,  {name:'score7'}]}, function(err, data){
    res.render('result_other', {result: data, title: 'Отчет из police'});
});
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

[$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/index.html#inc) accepts only numeric values, and can only operate on fields containing numbers.

Assuming the `text2` fields contains a number, `{$inc:{text2:11}}` should work.

Comment: **text2** contains a numeric value, but for some reason does not change the data.

Comment: In your query, you passed a string, not a numeric value.

Comment: but how to convey it in number? I do not understand

Comment: fixed everything but the result is the same (